# SailsJS, Socket IO 101 (Switching Protocols) pending forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I have been working on an application using SailsJS. Everything has been working fine until a couple of hours ago when I wasn't getting responses from `socket.get()`. I checked the network tab in chrome console and found that the last request is still pending.

Uri for request:

`ws://localhost:1337/socket.io/1/websocket/FBcw-Q4H3PLFXcIlb0GB`

Status code:

`101 Switching Protocols`

I have searched around and some people have been saying it is due to firewalls. So I disabled them but this didn't help. Some others have suggested defaulting to **xhr polling** so I did that but the same thing happens, a request to

`http://localhost:1337/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/4_gAWYQJtKdXhDFEcxHe?t=1395536371612`

just stays pending forever.

In response to the comment here is the request event:

```
socket.get('/session/create', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }, function (response) {
                console.log(response) // null
            });
```

The response is never returned and is always null in the callback. I even tried sending a response straight away and that isn't returned either. Example below:

```
// Session controller
module.exports = {  

    create: function (req, res) {
             return res.json({foo: 'bar'}, 200);
        }
}
```

Comment: That request is always going to say "pending" forever; that's just how web sockets work.  So that's not the source of your problem.  Can you post your actual `socket.get()` call, and the code that the server should be executing in response?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the request and controller code to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I have done some fiddling and I have found the issue (probably a silly mistake on my part).

I have shortcut urls enabled which in SailsJS means a request to **/foo/bar** will map to the **FooController.bar**

This worked fine until I added a wildcard route like the below example:

`get /:foo/:bar`

This is what seems to have broken the request. Since I was sending a request to `/session/create` and relied on shortcut routes without specifying an explicit route it was interpreted by the `:foo/:bar` route.

Lesson learned: Disable shortcut URLs and use proper routing.